# Using SPARQL to query DBPedia Company Information

Tags: rdf, sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I'm trying to query DBPedia using SPARQL only to find company information such as a description, and a logo.

I'm rather lost with devising the SPARQL Query to do this.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?subject 
                ?employees 
                ?homepage 
  WHERE 
    {
      ?subject  rdf:type               <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098>  .
      ?subject  dbpedia2:numEmployees  ?employees
        FILTER  ( xsd:integer(?employees) >= 50000 )                                     .
      ?subject  foaf:homepage          ?homepage                                         .
    } 
  ORDER BY  DESC(xsd:integer(?employees))
  LIMIT  20
```

I have come across the above query, which finds companies with over 50,000 emplayoees, but I don't understand such things as the rdf type being "http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098"

Well all I want to know is given a company name, how can I return a unique ID, logo and description? I just want 3 pieces of data back, which I can then store in my database.

Comment: I know that @gray saw it (and commented on it), but for the sake of others, there's a related question, [Given a list of company names, how to fetch company names, website url, year established, number of employees etc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12150399/1281433).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098>` in a query like the following is because (presumably), that's a class whose instances are companies. Asking for instances of the class is a way of asking for companies.

```
select * { ?s rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098> }
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20%7B%20%0D%0A?s%20a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

It's the same principle that lets us select Persons with:

```
select * { ?s a dbpedia-owl:Person }
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20%7B%20?s%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aPerson%20%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

As to your specific query, a typically good way to query DBpedia data is to start by looking at the data manually and finding the types of values you're interested in.  For instance, you might look at Apple, Inc., whose DBpedia resource is

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc., which redirects to
- http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple_Inc. which you can view in your browser.

For the kinds of information that you're looking for, important properties seem to be:

- rdfs:label "Apple" or "Apple Inc." (which you'd use to query against), or
- foaf:name "Apple Inc."
- foaf:depiction http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg, or
- dbpedia-owl:thumbnail http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/200px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png
- dbpedia-owl:abstract "english description"@en
- rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Company (to help narrow down the results)

You can simply use the resource IRI as the unique identifier.  Given all this, you can write a query like the following.  It has multiple results, though, because there are multiple possible logos, but so it goes.

```
select ?iri ?logo ?description {
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
       dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description ;
       rdfs:label "Apple Inc."@en ;
       foaf:depiction|dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?logo .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?iri%20?logo%20?description%20%7B%0D%0A#%20%20values%20?hasLogo%20%7B%20foaf%3adepiction%20dbpedia-owl%3athumbnail%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20?iri%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aCompany%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3aabstract%20?description%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20%22Apple%20Inc.%22@en%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3adepiction%7Cdbpedia-owl%3athumbnail%20?logo%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?description%29,%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

It would be nice to be able to use

```
foaf:name|rdfs:label "Apple In."@en
```

as well, but the endpoint says in that case that the estimated time is too great:

> Virtuoso 42000 Error The estimated execution time 9320 (sec) exceeds the limit of 3000 (sec).

I'm not sure how it estimates the time, but you can use some `optionals` and some `values` to work around it (but be sure to put `distinct` into the `select`):

```
select distinct ?iri ?logo ?description {
  values ?hasLogo { foaf:depiction dbpedia-owl:thumbnail }
  values ?hasName { foaf:name rdfs:label }
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
       dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description ;
       ?hasLName "Apple Inc."@en ;
       ?hasLogo ?logo .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
}
```

*Note: At time of writing, DBpedia's endpoint is very sluggish and under maintenance, so I'm not sure yet whether this last permutation actually hits the estimated time cutoff or not.  I **think** that it will go through, though.*

Comment: DBPedia was also going very slow for me yesterday, it made me think SPARQL was a poor solution for my task. But it is working now, and fast too! thank you for your excellent answer. And that last SPARQL worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get all companies one have to use LIMIT and OFFSET because usually public endpoints limits number of results per query. 
Based on @Joshua answer I wrote a small script that can be run to get all companies from public dbpedia endpoint. 
Here is the gist:
https://gist.github.com/szydan/e801fa687587d9eb0f6a

One can also modify the query and use it to get other entities.

Comment: Hey @szydan how would you FILTER for a particular industry within your sparql query in this gist? I tried: `}WHERE{
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company.
  OPTIONAL{  
       ?iri dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description.
       FILTER( lang(?description) = "en")
       FILTER (regex(?description, '^platform$')) .
  }` to see if I could find platform as a service companies...but i'm getting all kinds of results that don't have that word in the description. Perhaps the regex is wrong? Is there a way I could filter for `?industrySector dbpedia-owl:industry <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Platform_as_a_service>` ?

Comment: Hi so I've modified the part of the query to get companies which in description have a word "platform". Note that I've removed the optional 
`?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company.
  ?iri dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description.
  FILTER( lang(?description) = "en" && regex( ?description , ".*platform.*", "i") ) .` 
For the second part I asked a simple query for the pattern you mention 
`select * where {
?industrySector dbpedia-owl:industry <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Platform_as_a_service>
}
LIMIT 100` 
but on this public endpoint **http://dbpedia.org/sparql** I've got only 3 triples :-(