# How should one filter a list of companies by industry using SPARQL?

Tags: regex, sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to create a list of companies within a particular industry type (PaaS/SaaS) using dbpedia and sparql. I read [this post on creating a list of companies with a certain number of employees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693995/using-sparql-to-query-dbpedia-company-information), and I wanted to FILTER for a particular industry within a sparql query such as this one:

https://gist.github.com/szydan/e801fa687587d9eb0f6a

I tried this query (ommitting prefixes here):

```
CONSTRUCT{
    ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company;
         foaf:name ?companyName;
         dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description;
         owl:sameAs ?sameAs;
     dbpedia:countryCode ?countryCode;
         sindicetech:locationName ?locationName;
         sindicetech:locationCityName ?locationCityName
}WHERE{
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company.
  OPTIONAL{  
       ?iri dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description.
       FILTER( lang(?description) = "en")
       FILTER (regex(?description, '^platform$')) .
  }
  {
    OPTIONAL{  
      ?iri foaf:name ?companyName.
      FILTER( lang(?companyName) = "en")
    }
  }UNION{
    OPTIONAL{     
      ?iri rdfs:label ?companyName .
      FILTER( lang(?companyName) = "en")
    }
  }
  OPTIONAL{     
      ?iri owl:sameAs ?sameAs
  } 
  {
    OPTIONAL{     
      ?iri dbpedia:locationCountry ?country.
      ?country dbpedia:countryCode ?countryCode 
      FILTER( lang(?countryCode) = "en")
    }
  }UNION{  
    OPTIONAL{     
      ?iri dbpedia-owl:locationCountry ?country.
      ?country dbpedia:countryCode ?countryCode 
      FILTER( lang(?countryCode) = "en")
    } 
  }
  OPTIONAL{
      ?iri dbpedia-owl:location ?location.
      ?location dbpedia:name ?locationName
      FILTER( lang(?locationName) = "en")
  }
  OPTIONAL{
      ?iri dbpedia-owl:locationCity ?locationCity.
      ?locationCity rdfs:label ?locationCityName
      FILTER( lang(?locationCityName) = "en")

  }
}
LIMIT 100
```

to see if I could find platform as a service companies...but i'm getting all kinds of results that don't have that word in the description. Perhaps the `FILTER (regex(?description, '^platform$'))` regex is wrong? Is there a way I could filter for:

`?industrySector dbpedia-owl:industry <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Platform_as_a_service>`

Or perhaps I should be trying to narrow it down by filtering ontologically?

http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/OntologyProperty:Industry

I'm using [DBPEDIA's Virtuoso](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) to test these queries, and ideally, I'd like to arrive at a RDF hierarchy of categories with a CONSTRUCT query, that gives me all companies within a particular industry, such as PaaS, SaaS, etc. But I'm not married to CONSTRUCT queries, and I'll take any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Improving the query that you have

First, two notes.

1. You should compare language tags with **langMatches**, not with **lang(…) = …**.
2. SPARQL 1.1 includes property paths where you can use alternations, as well as **values**, whereby you can specify permissible values for a variable.  That means that instead of:

```sql
  {
    OPTIONAL{  
      ?iri foaf:name ?companyName.
      FILTER( lang(?companyName) = "en")
    }
  }UNION{
    OPTIONAL{     
      ?iri rdfs:label ?companyName .
      FILTER( lang(?companyName) = "en")
    }
  }
```

either

```sql
optional { 
  ?iri rdfs:label|foaf:name ?companyName .
  filter langMatches(lang(?companyName),"en")
}
```

or

```sql
values ?nameProperty { rdfs:label foaf:name }
optional { 
  ?iri ?nameProperty ?companyName .
  filter langMatches(lang(?companyName),"en")
}
```

Property paths can make some other parts of your query shorter, too.  E.g.,

```sql
?iri dbpedia-owl:locationCity ?locationCity.
?locationCity rdfs:label ?locationCityName
```

can be just:

```sql
?iri dbpedia-owl:locationCity/rdfs:label ?locationCityName
```

since you didn't use **?locationCity** anywhere.

Finally, as to

> i'm getting all kinds of results that don't have that word in the
>   description. Perhaps the FILTER (regex(?description, '^platform$'))
>   regex is wrong?

The regular expression doesn't quite do what you want it to:

```sql
FILTER (regex(?description, '^platform$'))
```

That will only match when the characters in the string are exactly "platform".  It seems more like you'd want to check whether the description *contains* the word platform, in which case you can use [**contains**](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains), as in **contains(?description,"platform")**.  But even if you update like that, you'll have

```sql
optional {
  ?iri dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description.
  filter contains(?description,"platform")
  filter langMatches(lang(?description),"en")
}
```

and that's still inside an **optional** block.  The whole point of **optional** is that you can get results even if the **optional** part doesn't match.  If you want to require that there is a description that contains the word platform, don't make it optional.

After all that, your query becomes:

```sql
prefix sindicetech: <urn:ex:sindicetech:>

construct {
    ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
         foaf:name ?companyName ;
         dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description ;
         owl:sameAs ?sameAs ;
         dbpedia:countryCode ?countryCode ;
         sindicetech:locationName ?locationName ;
         sindicetech:locationCityName ?locationCityName
}
where {
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
       dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description .
  filter langMatches(lang(?description),"en") .
  filter contains(?description,"platform") .
  optional {
    ?iri foaf:name|rdfs:label ?companyName.
    filter langMatches(lang(?companyName),"en")
  }
  optional {     
    ?iri owl:sameAs ?sameAs
  } 
  optional {
    ?iri (dbpedia:locationCountry|dbpedia-owl:locationCountry)/dbpedia:countryCode ?countryCode .
    filter langMatches(lang(?countryCode),"en")
  }
  optional {
    ?iri dbpedia-owl:location/dbpedia:name ?locationName
    filter langMatches(lang(?locationName),"en")
  }
  optional {
    ?iri dbpedia-owl:locationCity/rdfs:label ?locationCityName
    filter langMatches(lang(?locationCityName),"en")
  }
}
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20sindicetech%3A%20%3Curn%3Aex%3Asindicetech%3A%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconstruct%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Firi%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%3FcompanyName%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fdescription%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3FsameAs%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia%3AcountryCode%20%3FcountryCode%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sindicetech%3AlocationName%20%3FlocationName%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sindicetech%3AlocationCityName%20%3FlocationCityName%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Firi%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fdescription%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fdescription%29%2C%22en%22%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20contains%28%3Fdescription%2C%22platform%22%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Firi%20foaf%3Aname%7Crdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcompanyName.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3FcompanyName%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Firi%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3FsameAs%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Firi%20%28dbpedia%3AlocationCountry%7Cdbpedia-owl%3AlocationCountry%29%2Fdbpedia%3AcountryCode%20%3FcountryCode%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3FcountryCode%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Firi%20dbpedia-owl%3Alocation%2Fdbpedia%3Aname%20%3FlocationName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3FlocationName%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Firi%20dbpedia-owl%3AlocationCity%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlocationCityName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3FlocationCityName%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100%0D%0A&format=text%2Fturtle&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can see that the results are about companies with **"platform"** in their descriptions.

Note that none of them have any **dbpedia:countryCode** properties though.  I don't know where you found that property, but it doesn't appear to be used anywhere in DBpedia.  The query **select (count(*) as ?n) { ?x dbpedia:countryCode ?y }** returns **0**.

### A different approach

> Is there a way I could filter for:
>
> ```sql
> ?industrySector dbpedia-owl:industry <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Platform_as_a_service>
> ```

If you look at [http://dbpedia.org/resource/Platform_as_a_service](http://dbpedia.org/page/Platform_as_a_service) you'll that it's related to a number of companies (but not all that many) by a few different properties:

[image: dpbedia triples]

You might just ask for anything that's a company that's related to this by any property.  E.g.,

```sql
select distinct ?company where {
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
           ?property dbpedia:Platform_as_a_service .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fcompany%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20dbpedia%3APlatform_as_a_service%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can use that approach to get construct more detailed information, too.  I'd end up with something like this:

```sql
prefix sindicetech: <urn:ex:sindicetech:>

construct {
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
           foaf:name ?label ;
           dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
           owl:sameAs ?_company ;
           sindicetech:location [ sindicetech:city ?city ;
                                  sindicetech:country ?country ] .
}
where {
  ?company a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
           ?property dbpedia:Platform_as_a_service ;
           rdfs:label ?label ;
           dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract .
  filter langMatches(lang(?label),"en")
  filter langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en")
  optional {
    ?company owl:sameAs ?_company
  }
  optional { 
    ?company dbpedia-owl:location [ rdfs:label ?city ;
                                    dbpedia-owl:country/rdfs:label ?country ] .
    filter langMatches(lang(?city),"en")
    filter langMatches(lang(?country),"en")
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20sindicetech%3A%20%3Curn%3Aex%3Asindicetech%3A%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconstruct%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3F_company%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sindicetech%3Alocation%20%5B%20sindicetech%3Acity%20%3Fcity%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sindicetech%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%20%5D%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACompany%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20dbpedia%3APlatform_as_a_service%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcompany%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3F_company%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcompany%20dbpedia-owl%3Alocation%20%5B%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcity%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Acountry%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry%20%5D%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fcity%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fcountry%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fturtle&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: This is one of those answers that teaches you more about the problem (and language) that you bargained for. Wonderfully explained, laterally explored, and absolutely comprehensive. Grateful n00b here.